# Flutter setting property in Map causes UnsupportedError (Unsupported operation: read-only)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method inside a state class which calls setState, however whenever it is called it throws a `UnsupportedError (Unsupported operation: read-only)` and gives no other information. Can you see anything wrong with my code that would make it do this? I seems like this should be pretty straightforward...

```
Future _uploadFile(imageFile, imageFilename, String imageNumber) async {
    _user = await DBProvider.db.getUser();
    final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: 'gs://circle-fc687.appspot.com');
    StorageReference _storageRef = _storage.ref().child('users').child('${_user['uid']}').child('$imageFilename');

    final Directory systemTempDir = Directory.systemTemp;

    final File file = await File('${systemTempDir.path}/$imageFile').create();

    StorageUploadTask _uploadTask = _storageRef.putFile(file);

    await _uploadTask.onComplete;
    print('Upload complete');
    String downloadLink = await _storageRef.getDownloadURL();

    setState(() {
      _user['imageOne'] = downloadLink;
    });
}
```

**Edit**
calling `setState` is not the problem, as trying to update a Map property `_user['imageOne'] = downloadLink;` from within this method also causes the same error. This variable is not a final or anything like that, just `Map<String, dynamic>`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Usually DBs return immutable/unmodifiable data, so you have to clone it before changing:

```dart
final newUser = {
  ..._user,
  'imageOne': downloadLink
};
```

or

```
final newUser = Map.of(_user);
newUser['imageOne'] = downloadLink;
```

Though an unmodifiable map is inherited from the same Map class, it has a different runtime type that doesn't actually support []= operation.

Answer (score -1):

If this:

```
setState(() {
      _user['imageOne'] = downloadLink;
    });
```

is causing the error, it might be because `_user` is immutable. I would assume that `DBProvider.db.getUser()` returns something immutable and to update one of the properties you would need to make an explicit copy of the object and set the new value.

I don't know the package you are using for DB access, but in `flutter_moor` for example you get a `copyWith` method on the object coming from the DB where you can set the new values.

Comment: I'll give this a shot but I have TextField widgets that make changes to the same `_user` from within the `onChanged` callback which is why I'm confused